# How to create a domain model for entity with children and parent

Tags: typescript, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to create a domain model (aggregate) for entity which contains children and can have a parent one.
We have entity Package.
We can split package into smaller packages (children).
Every divided package has one parent Package.
Which part of domain should contain domain logic: aggregate or domain service? 
e.g. aggregate package has a method

```
split(splitParams: ISplitParameters): Package {
   // Split logic based on splitParams here
   const child = new Package(params);
   child.parent = this;
   this.children.push(child);
   return child;
}
```

Should method split return child or original package? 
What is the proper way to solve this?

I want my domain model be clean and idempotent by other parts of ddd (application and infrastructure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, it seems like `split` is a method on the `Package` entity. So the ubiquitous language would contain statements that indicate a Package can "split" itself. If that is the case, the `split` method should be in the `Package` aggregate.

If it were a factory method or a class method, I would suggest housing it in a Factory, rather than Domain services. Use Domain services only when you are handling two or more aggregates or very complex business logic.

If the child package is accessible only via `parent.children`, it makes sense to return the original package aggregate. You should always pass aggregate objects around, and access the child entities via the aggregate root.